# Remove ACTIVE classes from all other buttons when I click an other button in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to assign "active" to a button which I clicked on and remove active from the other buttons when I do so, I want to do this in Vanilla JS since I want to practice my skills. I have tried out similar issues on SO, however I can't get my code to work.

Ultimately I want to create a gallery filter for images taken from my DB in PHP which I added to my code as seen bellow based on button which is acive I want to show / hide the categories. The image receive a `class = someCategory` from the `image_category` column in my DB.

Help is appreciated.

I've tried to take similar issues under consideration. But I failed to make it work.

[Vanilla JS remove class from all other elements besides 'active' class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334613/vanilla-js-remove-class-from-all-other-elements-besides-active-class)

**HTML & PHP CODE:**

```
     <div id="category-buttons">
    <h5>Choose image category</h5>
      <button id="All" class="catgory-button active" >All Categories</button>
      <button id="CNC_Machining_button" class="catgory-button">CNC_Machining</button>
      <button id="HP_Die_Casting" class="catgory-button">HP Die Casting</button>
      <button id="Iron_Casting" class="catgory-button">Iron Casting</button>
      <button id="Steel_Casting" class="catgory-button">Steel Casting</button>
      <button id="Precision_Casting" class="catgory-button">Precision Casting</button>
      <button id="Aluminium_Casting" class="catgory-button">Aluminum Casting</button>
    </div>


<section class="gallery-links">
<div class="wrapper">

  <h2 class="product-gallery-title">Product Gallery</h2>

  <div class="gallery-container">
    <?php
    include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM gallery ORDER BY orderGallery DESC';
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
      echo 'SQL statement failed!';
    } else {
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //what's echoed out by the database

        echo '  <a class="images '.$row["image_category"].'" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].')">
                <div class="color-overlay">
                <h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
                <p>'.$row["descGallery"].'</p>
                </div>
                </a>';
      }
    }


    ?>  

  </div>
 </div>

<?php
```

**JS Code:**

```
    let btns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.category-button'));

    const handleClick = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      btns.forEach(node => {
        node.classList.remove('active');
      });
      e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
    }

    btns.forEach(node => {
      node.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
    });
```

**Relevant CSS CODE:**

```
    #category-buttons {
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 12.5%;
    margin: 10vh 10px;
    }

    .category-button {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 2px 0;;
    color: white;
    background: rgb(153, 124, 124);

    }

    .product-gallery-title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    width: 65%;
    margin: auto;
    }

    .gallery-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 13px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    justify-content: center;
    }

    .images{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

**Expected Result:**
On click, button receives `active` class and other buttons in scope lose them.

Comment: It would be good to see the HTML output not just the PHP, are there any elements with class .category_btn ?

Comment: @Matt Here you go: https://pasteboard.co/HXm3DPn.png
I also changed to '.category-button' It works now with the code of Firline. (See answer bellow) However, all stay active.

Comment: From what I can see from the image let btns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.category_btn')); won't select anything, there are no class="category_btn" elements

Comment: Here is an updated image. As mentioned above, it works however all buttons stay active, even when clicking on other buttons in scope.https://pasteboard.co/HXm9h8f.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do for example is to store the active button in a global variable and use that variable to remove the class from it when another button is clicked.

So something like this:

```js
let btns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.category_btn'));
let activeButton = null;

// The button which would be used to add 'active' class to
// all the buttons.
let allButton = document.querySelector('#All');

const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
  // Checks that the activeButton is defined (initially it's null).
  // Also checks that the button that was clicked is not the button which is
  // already active to avoid removing the active class on double click.
  if (activeButton != null && activeButton != e.currentTarget) {
    activeButton.classList.remove('active');
  }
  activeButton = e.currentTarget;
}

btns.forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
});

// Listen to a click event from the "allButton" and when it's clicked,
// loop through the buttons array and add 'active' class to all buttons
// in it.
allButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    btns.forEach(btn => {
        btn.classList.add('active');
    })
});
```

I'm not currently anywhere where I can test and verify that it works, but I see no reason why it would not work.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my code. It works now. However, all stay active.

Comment: Do you know how I would need to change the code so that one button would assign active to all buttons in scope?

Comment: Had a chance to try it out now and realized that the initial null value of the activeButton was the cause of the error here. Should work with the above fixes now.

Comment: Works like a charm, great thanks also for the comments. I'll accept this as answer. As a bonus, could you propose a code that when the button with id="All" is clicked all buttons become active.?

Comment: Included in the code snippet above now. If you want to add the class 'active' also to the id="All" button, just insert allButton.classList.add('active'); below the btn.classList.add('active');

Comment: That works fine, just one little tweek would make it perfect, because right not the active class remains on all buttons when clicking the All button and after that clicking other buttons.